# Java regex building from wildcards

Tags: java, regex

I have a need to translated strings containing text and wildcards (asterisks, "*") into string containing text and regexes.

For instance the string:

> http://myapp.example.com/fizz/buzz/myapp-1.5.*.jar

Would be converted into:

> http://myapp.example.com/fizz/buzz/myapp-1.5.[0-9a-zA-Z.-]+.jar

Where `[0-9a-zA-Z.-]+` is the regex replacing it (a regex that matches on 1+ digits, alphabet chars, periods or dashes).

Here is my code:

```
// inputStr is same as first example above (containing asterisks)
// strWithRegex is same as 2nd example above
String strWithRegex = inputStr.replaceAll("*", "[0-9a-zA-Z.-]+")
```

When I run this I get:

```
Caught: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*
^
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*
^
    at java_lang_String$replaceAll$2.call(Unknown Source)
    ...rest of stack trace omitted for brevity
```

Where am I going awry? Also, not 100% sure my regex is even correct, it needs to match 1+:

- Digits (0-9); or
- Upper/lowercase Roman alphabet chars (a-z, A-Z); or
- Periods (".")
- Hyphens ("-")

Comment: You should escape the `*` using `\\*` because `*` has a *special meaning* in *regex*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First parameter of method `replaceAll()` is pattern. Since `*` has special meaning in patterns you have to escape it using `\`. But easier way is just use `replace()` method instead.

EDIT.

BTW I typically use `str.replace("*", ".*")` instead enumerating all possible characters.

Comment: Can also use [Pattern.quote(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to avoid excessive and confusing `\` in string.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, good idea. However in this case IMHO it is overkill.